# libEGL warning: MESA-LOADER: failed to open crocus

Tags: gentoo, mesa

My Gentoo Linux UI shows me this error on my PC (which has Intel GPU & Nvidia GPU both).

```
libEGL warning: MESA-LOADER: failed to open crocus: /usr/lib64/dri/crocus_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib64/dri, suffix _dri)
```

And there is no `crocus_dri.so` in the path.
only

`kms_swrast_dri.so`

`nouveau_dri.so`

`nouveau_drv_video.so`

`r300_dri.so`

`r600_dri.so`

`r600_drv_video.so`

`swrast_dri.so`

are exist.

What is the `crocus_dri.so`?

Do I have to add some kind of USE flags when I do `emerge media-libs/mesa`?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly these errors (and others) before core dump,on an HP Desktop, when I upgraded to Mint 21.1 and tried to run Eagle 9.5.2 and 9.6.2.  On a different machine with Mint 19.1 and Eagle 9.5.2 I had a different error: "

"symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0" on ...
./eagle: symbol lookup error: /usr/ lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so .0: undefined symbol: xcb_dri3_get_supported_modifiers Environment"

I queried that error for a solution and found this:
"Solution: Follow these steps: Open Terminal; Move to the directory .../eagle-9.6.2/lib; Run the command rm libxcb*; Launch Eagle".

I followed the instruction and it allowed Eagle to run on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `VIDEO_CARDS="intel"` to build crocus (the OpenGL driver for Intel GPU generations 4-7).